# Performant M.2 SATA PCIe Adapter Card That Takes Multiple M.2 SSDs—Preferably RAID-capable

Tags: ssd, pcie, sata, raid-controller, adapter

I’ve found a product that I may want to purchase since I have spare M.2 SATA SSDs lying around:

- [StarTech.com PEXM2SAT3422](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/m2-raid-controller-card~PEXM2SAT3422)

I’m hoping to find out if something better exists out on the market. Priorities:

1. Takes more than one M.2 SATA SSD
2. Does not require additional data (SATA) cables to be connected to the motherboard
3. Supports TRIM
4. Has Spanning/RAID-0 mode (multiple SSDs seen as one device)
5. Bandwidth of both drives combined

The Startech product mentioned before supports 1 to 5, but not all at once; RAID mode does not pass TRIM along to the underlying SSDs. So it seems that 3 and 4 are mutually exclusive there. The [Startech 25S22M2NGFFR](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/dual-m2-ssd-sata-adapter~25S22M2NGFFR) *does* support TRIM, but its bandwidth is gimped by the SATA interface, and it does not support TRIM for RAID-0 anyhow; spanning mode is counted as “RAID” and StarTech says it does not support TRIM except in JBOD mode which is not what I want.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer hardware RAID over software RAID?

Comment: Also, it may actually be cheaper to get an older RAID card and use standard SATA to M.2 adapters. Would you be okay with that?

Comment: Hardware is preferable to software. The computers I'm putting them in are old enough that they don't have M.2 support and they have pretty anemic CPUs.

Comment: My mini-ITX builds have only one PCIe slot.

Comment: Gotcha. Out of curiosity, why are you putting an SSD RAID0 in an old computer? Also, I meant [this sort of M.2 to SATA adapter](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/aplusautomation/vendorimages/fb602856-2955-4c3b-8bd2-3513617893dc.jpg._CB335275049_.jpg), which wouldn't take any additional PCI-e slots.

Comment: Well, I prefer to have the best-performing parts with the smallest footprint. Once the old computers crap out, I can put them to use in new builds where the performance can be taken advantage of. Storage devices and peripherals along with network interface cards are a few of those things that can be harvested for new builds years down the road and not be too obsolete. I've given away RAM and CPUs to friends before and they could never use the outdated tech due to motherboard incompatibility. PCIe has been great in that area. I buy a 10 gbps NIC now and that will age pretty well. No e-waste.

Comment: SSD RAID0 is pretty excessive for most workloads. What're you planning on using that storage for?